# Using the LinkedIn API with one oauth connection

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth, linkedin-api

I want to have my LinkedIn app connect to the API, and then let users of my website get data from the LinkedIn API through my app.  I don't want to require my users to connect to LinkedIn, because none of the data I need is on their profiles.  Everything I need I can get through my personal OAuth connection.  For example, company lookup.

In short, is there a way to pass through a LinkedIn authentication for users of my website, such that only one access token is fielding the requests?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes it can be done, but you'll be breaking the LinkedIn TOS, and you'll be getting yourself in trouble with LinkedIn.

Check the LinkedIn TOS, or take a look at a [Linkedin API guide](http://thoughtengineer.com/linkedin-development-managers-guide/) I have written which summarizes what can or what cannot be done, without breaking their terms of service.

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing. How can this be done (as you say its technically possible)?